# Would the braket extension in MathJax v3 be appropriate and useful for this site?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, mathjax

Since our math editor is currently on the news, here's one aspect worth considering.

One thing that's been pointed out on the Meta.MathOverflow threads ([here](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4858) and [here](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4863)) is that v3 of MathJax has been released recently (IIUC last April) and that it is faster than the current v2.7. (MathJax v3 is also discussed on Meta SE in [this thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/338933/next-math-renderer-mathjax-v3-versus-katex), which hasn't received significant developer attention.) It doesn't seem to break anything we rely on, but [looking at the list of changes](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/upgrading/v2.html#v2-jax-changes), one thing that sticks out is [the addition of the `braket` extension](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/input/tex/extensions/braket.html#tex-braket), which could potentially be very useful here.

The last time we discussed something similar was [the `physics` extension](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10989/why-dont-we-have-the-physics-mathjax-extension-enabled-should-we), and there it does look like there are good reasons not to include it, but `braket` is smaller and nobler and it could do quite a bit to help with on-boarding.

In any case:

- Assuming a switch to v3 is coming, would the `braket` extension make sense?
- Would it break any existing posts which define their own bra/ket notation?
- Would we want to have it enabled?

Comment: There are a few hundred posts that define their own bra or ket: https://data.stackexchange.com/physics/query/1369090. I'm not sure if they would break or not from adding this extension, but fixing them should be doable in any case.

Comment: @Chris: They shouldn't break. MathJax allows the redefinition of existing commands (even using `\newcommand`; AFAIK it treats `\newcommand` and `\renewcommand` identically), so the custom definitions will just override the extension.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen I think you’re right, but “shouldn’t break” is wishful thinking unless there is testing involved.

Comment: What's the difference between using that and "|\psi\rangle" ($|\psi\rangle$)? Does it just make it a tad quicker to write that? If that's all, then is it worth it if it there's even a chance of breaking all those posts noted above?

Comment: @JohnDumancic Even if every single one of them breaks (and it's likely they won't), I don't consider that to be a high cost to pay (fixing <300 posts will only take a few days if people pitch in). If there are no concerns about the stability of the braket extension, then the only concern I see is compatibility with other SE sites. (But, as noted before by others, perhaps that should not be a goal.)

Comment: @JohnDumancic indeed, with single bras and kets there's not much difference. But some complicated brakets, especially those containing fractions (or differentiation operators) take some careful playing with `\left` and `\right` for all components (two angles and two mids) or resorting to `\big` etc.. Just using `\Braket` should be much easier.

Answer (score 23):

Just as a place to gather votes as a clear signal:

**Yes, the braket extension is appropriate and useful. It should be enabled on this site whenever the MathJax version is upgraded to v3.**

(Vote up if you agree, down if you don't.)